# How can I use a VPN connection on Eduroam?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, internet

I'm an italian student. I recently bought a VPN from Private Internet Access. Everything works fine from home and my mobile but it does not on University's WiFi Eduroam. Does anyone know if there's a way to go through VPN in Eduroam?

I can be more specific if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, please be more specific.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: Take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. This looks a lot like configuration problem and not like a question about information security. We do not know the setup of the eduroam infrastructure - and I suspect neither do you - so it's impossible to tell why this doesn't work. You should probably ask this in the "Private Internet Access" forums.

Comment: PIA has a strong support forum that may be better for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How lucky! I just solved the problem myself looking [here](https://www.eduroam.us/node/96). This is a guide for the US but it works also in Italy.

I am using OpenVPN so i just had to connect on port 1194 with udp.